# spawn EACCES in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, kivy, visual-studio-code

I configured a new debug environment in Visual Studio Code under OS X.

```
{
    "name": "Kivy",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "/Applications/Kivy3.app/Contents/Frameworks/python/3.5.0/bin",
    "program": "${file}",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
},
```

When it runs, it said **"Error: spawn EACCES"**
I assume this is because my current user doesn't habe the according permission to this folder since it is under the root rather than my user folder.

I tried the 2 methods, nothing works, how to handle it?

1. create a soft link from that folder to my own folder, but still same error
2. sudo VSC, still the same

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

@Albert Gao,

The path you have specified above doesn't contain the name of the python file. You need to provide the path to the file, include the file name. I believe you need to change it as follows:

`"pythonPath": "/Applications/Kivy3.app/Contents/Frameworks/python/3.5.0/bin/python",`

If that doesn't work, then type the following into your command (terminal) window:
- `which python`
- Next copy that path and paste it into `settings.json`

Comment: Similar fix for setting up Chrome for js debugging: `"runtimeExecutable": "/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the spawn error above while using **OpenOCD** for the Raspberry Pi Pico, make sure that your "**cortex-debug.openocdPath**" in "*settings.json*" is set to "*<Path_to_openocd_executable>***/openocd**" for example:

`"cortex-debug.openocdPath": "/home/vbhunt/pico/openocd/src/openocd", "cortex-debug.gdbPath": "/bin/gdb-multiarch"`

This is a specific instance for the Raspberry Pi Pico of @Albert Gao's excellent answer.